# lubuntu guest looses virtualbox guest additions

Tags: guest-additions

Set-up: Virtualbox under windows7. lubuntu as guest.

Problem: Need lbuntu to run with resolution 1024x660 for laptop window. Standard resolutions do not include 1024x660.

Solution BUT problem:
Installing Guest Additions, then clicking virtualbox "View->Adjust window size" and "View->Auto-resize guest display"
Monitor preferences then show 1024x660. Select and all seems just ducky!

Reboot and lubuntu restarts in 1024x660.

BUT, when the virtual machine is shutdown and restarted (rather than rebooted) we are back to square zero. The guest additions are gone, must be reinstalled and whole process repeated to make 1024x660 available!!!

So, what is going on and how can I make the guest additions stay and 1024x660 stay in place?

Additionally, the same problem applies to the shared folder, which disappears after a shutdown/restart until the additions are reinstalled.

Thanks for any insight.

BTW, this does not happen with debian guest.